# Spring Boot Web (Gradle config) breaks when I add AOP/Advice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-aop

I'm faily sure this is a missconfiguration, I just don't know which part since the AOP tutorials i found all used Maven, but I use Gradle.

So I took the project that start.spring.io creates (Kotlin 1.5.21, Gradle 7.1.1, Spring Boot 2.5.3) with a starter for spring-boot-starter-web.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
}
```

Then I added

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
```

and an Advice

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION) @MustBeDocumented
annotation class UserAuthorized(val roles: Array<String>)

@Component @Aspect
class UserAuthorizedAdvice {
    @Pointcut("@target(com.example.springbootplayground2.auth.UserAuthorized)")
    fun userAuthorizedMethods() {}

    @Before("userAuthorizedMethods()")
    fun checkIfUserHasRequiredRole(jp: JoinPoint) {...}
}
```

Now the app crashes at startup (error messages at the end). I tried to fix it with adding the *@EnableAspectJAutoProxy* annotation, but it didn't help.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
class SpringbootPlayground2Application
```

On Linux this crashes with

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'errorPageCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'errorPageCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dispatcherServletRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'dispatcherServletRegistration' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multipartConfigElement' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "cause" is null
```

caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "cause" is null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException.<init>(CodeGenerationException.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:587) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
```

On MacOs (M1-cpu) this crashes with `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` caused by

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9c83fa9f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:180) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f87b4803.getWebServer(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
                ... 25 common frames omitted
```

**Update**

here you can find a [minimal version of my project](https://github.com/simon-void/SpringWebAOP-MCVE)

**Update2**

the project now has a [solution branch](https://github.com/simon-void/SpringWebAOP-MCVE/tree/solution) incorporating kriegaex' fix.

Comment: Before asking you for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me to reproduce your problem, against my habit I am risking a guess: Did you try limiting the pointcut scope, adding `&& within(my.base.pkg..*)`?

Comment: my pointcut now looks like this: `@Pointcut("@target(com.example.springbootplayground2.auth.UserAuthorized) && within(com.example..* )")`. Positive: the application no longer fails at startup. Negative: the advice isn't added even to my own classes, specifically to `com.example.springbootplayground2.auth.AuthTestController`

Comment: Like I thought, your pointcut was too broad. But that now no aspect is applied, should not happen. Are you sure there is no typo, such as `com.example.*` (single dot) instead of `com.example..*` (double dot)? Are Spring AOP and component scan configured correctly? Does another simple pointcut such as `execution(* my.package.MyClass.myMethod(..))` work? I think, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub would help.

Comment: a) I don't understand how the pointcut could have  been too broad (though it certainly seems so). It's not like an annotation `com.example.springbootplayground2.auth.UserAuthorized` is likely to exist somewhere else. b) no, I don't see any typo in my pointcut now c) Spring AOP is likely misconfigured, but I don't know any better but luckily you can check in d) the MCVE: https://github.com/simon-void/SpringWebAOP-MCVE

Comment: (a) Because `@target` is a dynamic pointcut, possible targets of which can only be determined during runtime. Therefore, Spring creates proxies for all components it finds, including Spring-internal ones. With AspectJ you would not have this problem, so if you wish you can switch to AspectJ. But actually, limiting the pointcut scope is far easier in this case. (d) I am going to take a look. Thanks for the GitHub link.

Comment: Update: I hate Gradle. Whenever I am opening a Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA, it downloads the world, even if I add `mavenLocal()` to the config after cloning the repository. This takes ages. 15 minutes and still downloading, I cannot even start a single build. Why don't people just use Maven and be happy? _Sorry for the rant, but this is the 50th time this happens to me, whenever I am nice (stupid?) enough to try and help a Gradle user._

Comment: just executing `./gradlew bootRun` should be enough to start the app (like mentioned in the Readme). It will download a lot the first time. To the best of my knowledge gradle caches the library (at .m2/) independently of the `mavenLocal()` in repositories.

Comment: Yeah, Gradle downloads stuff which it shouldn't because it is in `~/.m2/repository` already. Sorry, I had a dinner appointment. Meanwhile stupid Gradle finished downloading the world and itself. So inefficient! Why do all Gradle projects use the same "I am the centre of the universe and need everything downloaded from scratch" defaults? Anyway, now I had a chance to look at your code. See upcoming answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I was so focused on helping you fix your scoping problem and then thinking about your description of the aspect not being picked up, that I overlooked the obvious:

You are simply using the wrong pointcut type. `@target()` is for type annotations, while you use a method annotation requiring an `@annotation()` pointcut:

```kotlin
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.springbootplayground2.UserAuthorized)")
fun userAuthorizedMethods() {}
```

Now your aspect kicks in, and because `@annotation()` can be determined statically, you do not even need `&& within(...)`. But it is always a good idea to add it as a safeguard.

Lesson learned for you: Always try presenting all relevant code, always post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you are not sure where the error is located. You did not post your controller with the annotated method, otherwise I might have noticed right away. Now I only had a chance to notice the glitch after cloning your repository and waiting for Gradle to do its bandwidth-eating download thing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll delete my comment to avoid edits.